# Very slow loading time for parsing annual reports

Tags: python, web-scraping, delay

I am trying to scrape the SEC Edgar S&P500 annual reports with Python 3 and receive very slow loading time with some links. My current code works well for most of the report links, but returns only half of the website content for other links (e.g., the link below).

Is there a way around this? I am happy if the result is a text file without any weird html characters and only contains all text for the "end-user"

```
# import libraries
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils


# define the url to specific html_text file
new_html_text = r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/718877/000104746919000788/0001047469-19-000788.txt"

html = req.get(new_html_text)

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
textfile = doc.body.text
textfile = doc.body.unescape() # Converting HTML entities
utils.saveFile("test.txt", textfile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that your data contains multiple bodies. I'm sorry I didn't notice that before. See if the following code works.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
# define the url to specific html_text file
new_html_text = r"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/718877/000104746919000788/0001047469-19-000788.txt"

html = req.get(new_html_text,timeout=300) # Add timeout
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
texts = []
bodys = doc.selects('body|BODY') # Get all
for body in bodys:
  texts.append(body.unescape()) # Converting HTML entities
utils.saveFile("test.txt", "\n".join(texts))
```